# Условие для шаблона tpl

Tags: php, smarty, tpl

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть шаблон tpl для вывода изображений в котором для вывода alt и title используются переменные, но для 2 категорий (иконки в меню и изображения блога) на сайте они выводятся пустыми, видимо из бд подтягиваются данные для остальных, а для них таких данных нет.

Собственно вопрос в том, как прописать условие для вывода alt? Достаточно прописать alt="image"

Мои попытки добавить условие перед тегом img и внутри него, привели к 503 ошибке на сайте. Честно скажу что первый раз работаю с таким синтаксисом и возможно я просто не правильно прописываю или логика должна быть другая.

Код шаблона:

```
{strip}

{if $capture_image}
    {capture name="image"}
{/if}

{$image_data = $images|fn_image_to_display:$image_width:$image_height}
{$generate_image = $image_data.generate_image && !$external}
{$show_no_image = $show_no_image|default:true}
{$image_additional_attrs = $image_additional_attrs|default:[]}
{$image_link_additional_attrs = $image_link_additional_attrs|default:[]}

{if $image_data}
    {$image_additional_attrs["alt"] = $image_data.alt}
    {$image_additional_attrs["title"] = $image_data.alt}
    {$image_link_additional_attrs["title"] = $images.detailed.alt}
{/if}

{if !$obj_id}
    {if $image_data.image_path}
        {$obj_id = $image_data.image_path|crc32}
    {elseif $image_id}
        {$obj_id = $image_id|crc32}
    {else}
        {$obj_id = uniqid()}
    {/if}
{/if}

{hook name="common:image"}
{if $show_detailed_link}
    <a id="det_img_link_{$obj_id}" {if $image_data.detailed_image_path && $image_id}data-ca-image-id="{$image_id}"{/if} class="{$link_class} {if $image_data.detailed_image_path}cm-previewer ty-previewer{/if}" data-ca-image-width="{$images.detailed.image_x}" data-ca-image-height="{$images.detailed.image_y}" {if $image_data.detailed_image_path}href="{$image_data.detailed_image_path}" {$image_link_additional_attrs|render_tag_attrs nofilter}{/if}>
{/if}
{if $image_data.image_path}
    {** products:product_image_object is deprecated **}
    {hook name="products:product_image_object"}
        {$image_attributes = $image_additional_attrs|default:[]}
        {if $obj_id && !$no_ids}
            {$image_attributes.id = "det_img_{$obj_id}"}
        {/if}
        {if $image_data.width && !$image_attributes.width}
            {$image_attributes.width = $image_data.width}
        {/if}
        {if $image_data.height && !$image_attributes.height}
            {$image_attributes.height = $image_data.height}
        {/if}
        {if $generate_image}
            {$image_attributes["data-ca-image-path"] = $image_data.image_path}
        {/if}
        {if $generate_image}
            {$image_initial_src = "{$images_dir}/icons/spacer.gif"}
        {else}
            {$image_initial_src = $image_data.image_path}
        {/if}
        {if $lazy_load}
            {$image_attributes["data-src"] = $image_initial_src}
        {else}
            {$image_attributes.src = $image_initial_src}
        {/if}
        {if $image_onclick}
            {$image_attributes.onclick = $image_onclick}
        {/if}
        <img itemprop="contentUrl" class="ty-pict {$valign} {$class} {if $lazy_load}lazyOwl{/if} {if $generate_image}ty-spinner{/if} cm-image" {$image_attributes|render_tag_attrs nofilter} />
        
        {if $show_detailed_link}
            <svg class="ty-pict__container" aria-hidden="true" width="{$image_data.width}" height="{$image_data.height}" viewBox="0 0 {$image_data.width} {$image_data.height}" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); z-index: -1;">
                <rect fill="transparent" width="{$image_data.width}" height="{$image_data.height}"></rect>
            </svg>
        {/if}
    {/hook}
    {elseif $show_no_image}
    <span class="ty-no-image" style="height: {$image_height|default:$image_width}px; width: {$image_width|default:$image_height}px; ">{include_ext file="common/icon.tpl" class="ty-icon-image ty-no-image__icon" title=__("no_image")}</span>
{/if}
{if $show_detailed_link}
    {if $images.detailed_id}
        <span class="ty-previewer__icon hidden-phone"></span>
    {/if}
</a>
{/if}
{/hook}

{if $capture_image}
    {/capture}
    {capture name="icon_image_path"}
        {$image_data.image_path}
    {/capture}
    {capture name="detailed_image_path"}
        {$image_data.detailed_image_path}
    {/capture}
{/if}

{/strip}
```

Comment: откуда берется ваш alt ? в коде ничего про него нет. казалось бы достаточно было бы написать что-то вроде `alt="{$image_data.alt|default:'image'}"` но поскольку это самый непонятный шаблон который я в жизни видел, то мб предположение и не корректно. Казалось бы шаблоны призваны упрощать понимаете верстки и ее наглядность Тут что-то ситуация обратная

Comment: alt и title формируются в теге img благодаря вот этому {$image_attributes|render_tag_attrs nofilter}, в нем же указанном, тут смысл в том что бы написать здесь условие или в теге или до него(незнаю как правильно) и скажем по классам прописать что с такими-то 2 классам тег img содержит alt="image" и это не будет затрагивать все остальные, если я правильно объяснил))

Comment: у вас же есть строка `{$image_additional_attrs["alt"] = $image_data.alt}` вот там и напишите дополнительно условие какое надо